# Receive Callback from Service

Tags: android, aidl

Is there any mechanism to receive a callback from service through AIDL without any client intervention.Already i have implemented a two way communication through AIDL, but still i couldn't figure out how to sent a callback without a client call.Any insights into this will be very helpful.

Comment: iread this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: @pskink..I already went through it and I have a service running too..what I need to implement is a callback without a client intervention

Comment: go to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html then ^F callback

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here are two [Client](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClientEx/) and [service](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteServiceEx/) showing a remote client/service with callbacks.

For sending notification to App from service see

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Notifications

Comment: I have seen this example, I hope it is sending a callback request through button onclick. Also I don't want to use notifications as I will be sending data to fill some text box.